# SQL help, heirarchical table data

Tags: sql-server

I am developing a facebook type application and I am trying to develop a good query to get the latest messages. The messages can be a new thread (parentID empty guid) or a reply. What a I need is a query to get the first 10, or 10-20, or 20-30 Threads that are either the newest or have the latsest replies, I hope you get the idea

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ParentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[MessageDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I have a query that sort of works, as it can get the top 10, 20 3o results ect.

```
SELECT ym.* FROM
(
  SELECT top 20 TopId, MAX(MessageDateTime) as Mess FROM
  (

        SELECT
        CASE ParentId WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN Id ELSE ParentId END AS TopId, MessageDateTime
        FROM Messages

  ) As Temp
  GROUP BY TopId order by Mess desc)
  AS table2
  INNER JOIN Messages ym
  ON ym.id = TopId
```

The main problem is that there may be no replies, hence the case statemnt.
Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: It would help if ParentId is allowed to be NULL when there is no parent.  Then you could use a coalesce instead of a case.  Still chewing on an answer as the data is described.

Comment: It seems that this will only return the parent messages and/or messages with no children.  Is this handled in a separate query, or should this also be returning the children?

Answer (score 1):

As I said above, it would help if ParentId is allowed to be NULL when there is no parent.  Then you could use a coalesce instead of a case.

This is close to what you have above.  Like above, it will only return top-level messages (parents or messages without children) as this query is also based on Id.

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE Id IN
(SELECT TOP 20
 CASE ParentId WHEN '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN Id ELSE ParentId END AS TopId
 FROM Messages ORDER BY MessageDateTime DESC)
```

If you allowed NULLS, it could be cleaned up like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE Id IN
(SELECT TOP 20
 coalesce(ParentId, Id) AS TopId
 FROM Messages ORDER BY MessageDateTime DESC)
```

And then it would be trivial to adjust the query to include both the original message and replies:

```
SELECT *
FROM Messages
WHERE coalesce(ParentId, Id) IN
(SELECT TOP 20
 coalesce(ParentId, Id) AS TopId
 FROM Messages ORDER BY MessageDateTime DESC)
```

Hope this helps.  If not, please explain what I am missing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tevo, There really is no problem changing ParentID to accept NULLS, it certainly simpifies things, and simpler is always better IMO.